# Wordpress on a local machine redirecting to xampp dashboard page

Tags: redirect, theme-customizer, localhost, xampp

I just decided to learn Wordpress, I created new site successfully with name of 'unique-university' using flywheel but when I click 'OPEN SITE' It redirect me to Xamppp dashboard page 'http://localhost/dashboard/'. I just try to google this issue but still not able to resolve this issue so I'm hoping some kind of help to kick start my learning in wordpress .
here is my '.htaccess' code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /uniqueuniversity/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the rewriteBase as well

replace `RewriteBase /` with `RewriteBase /uniqueuniversity/`